# VBA Macro to copy and paste sheets into new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I do a report every day in which I have to copy and paste several sheets into a new workbook titled Report (today's date).

In my report I have 4 sheets : Customers, Orders, Country, ID.

Customer and Country are a simple copy and paste from the master file, but Orders and ID are filtered data from one of my sheets in the master file. Orders is filtered to "Complete" and Id is everything except ID 200 and 500.

I tried building a macro based on this solution found here :
http://www.hivmr.com/db/ack717pc8f88jpdsf7838pcaspkcsdmd

The copy and paste works but I am unable to copy and paste multiple sheets/ rename sheets and filter the data.

Edit:

```
Sub CopyInNewWB()
    'has been tested 
    Dim newWS, WS As Worksheet 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 
    Set newWS = Workbooks.Add.Sheets("Sheet1") 
    WS.Cells.Copy 
    newWS.Cells.PasteSpecial xlValues Application.CutCopyMode = False 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've been working with?

Comment: My apologies i thought i posted it

Comment: Sub CopyInNewWB()
'has been tested
Dim newWS, WS As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set newWS = Workbooks.Add.Sheets("Sheet1")
WS.Cells.Copy
newWS.Cells.PasteSpecial xlValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Comment: It is better to edit your question and include that code rather than post in as a comment.  The formatting is limited in comments and as you can see, it all just runs together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No clue how your filtered sheets are set up, but this method will copy the sheets in your master exactly how they are currently filtered to a new workbook:

```
Sub CopyInNewWB()
Dim wbO As Workbook, wbN As Workbook

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wbO = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbN = Workbooks.Add

wbO.Sheets("Customers").Copy wbN.Sheets(1)
wbO.Sheets("Orders").Copy wbN.Sheets(2)
wbO.Sheets("Country").Copy wbN.Sheets(3)
wbO.Sheets("ID").Copy wbN.Sheets(4)

wbN.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
wbN.Sheets("Customers").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ErrHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this it works perfecty however is there any way to tell the macro to filter the data? My data is set up in tables so the filters are just your basic filters. Every day i filter the order sheet to just completed (i have a heading for this in which it is a filter) and copy and paste into a new sheet, then i unfilter and filter the column entitled ID to everything except 200 and 500. If there is any way to do this it would be greatly appreciated and thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd need to see some sample data and know which sheets from the master are being filtered/copied to where in the report